# getJSON unable to get child value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am getting data from a API. The format from the API is as follows:

```js
{
   "total":1,
   "launches":[
  {
     "name":"Falcon 9 Full Thrust | BulgariaSat-1",
     "net":"June 23, 2017 18:10:00 UTC",
     "location":{
        "pads":[
           {
              "name":"Launch Complex 39A, Kennedy Space Center, FL",
              "agencies":[
                 {
                    "name":"SpaceX"
                 },
                 {
                    "name":"National Aeronautics and Space Administration"
                 }
              ]
           }
        ],
        "name":"Kennedy Space Center, FL, USA"
     },
     "rocket":{
        "name":"Falcon 9 Full Thrust",
        "agencies":[
           {
              "name":"SpaceX"
           }
        ],
        "infoURL":"http://www.spacex.com/falcon9"
     },
     "missions":[
        {
           "name":"BulgariaSat-1"
        }
     ]
  }
   ],
   "count":1
}
```

The jQuery I use to get retrieve the JSON is:

```js
$.getJSON('https://launchlibrary.net/1.2/launch/next/1', function(data) {
  data.launches.forEach(function(d) {
    $('#launch-main-name').append('<p class="rocket-main-data">' + d.name + '</p>');
    $('#launch-main-date').append('<p class="rocket-main-data">' + d.net + '</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="launch-main-name"></p>
<p id="launch-main-date"></p>
```

The problem I have been having is that I am unable to get any data from the grand-child element in the "launches" array: such as "location" -> "pads" -> "name". But I am able to get, for example the "name" and "net" data from the "launches" array.

I have tried some answers that I found on this website, but none of them worked.

**TL;DR** How do you make my getJSON target the grand-child element in the array?

Comment: `d.locations.pads`, as `pads` is an array you have to iterate it. like `d.locations.pads[0].name`

Comment: also you haven't given us an example of how you are currently trying to access the grandchild element

Comment: @Satpal : Little typo: it is `location`, not `locations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$.getJSON('https://launchlibrary.net/1.2/launch/next/1', function(data) {
  data.launches.forEach(function(d) {
    $('#launch-main-name').append('<p class="rocket-main-data">' + d.name + '</p>');
    $('#launch-main-date').append('<p class="rocket-main-data">' + d.net + '</p>');
    d.location.pads.forEach(function(l){
      $('#launch-main-name').append('<p class="rocket-main-data">' + l.name + '</p>');
      l.agencies.forEach(function(a){
      $('#launch-main-name').append('<p class="rocket-main-data">' + a.name + '</p>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="launch-main-name"></p>
<p id="launch-main-date"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kknehw7/

Pads is also an array, so have to loop over this, too.

```
data.launches.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(d.name);
  console.log(d.net);

  d.location.pads.forEach(function(p) {
    console.log(p.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the grandchildren the same way, ie. `d.location.pads[0].name`

You have to see if it's an array or an object. Basically, the complete path would be:

```
var jString = { // your object }
jString.launches[0].location.pads[0].name
```